# What's the proper way to empty an HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'd like to know how to clear an HTML5 Canvas with elements rendered on it, or paint it with a solid color, or both.

Really, I just want the thing sort of reset. **What's the proper way to empty the canvas and/or set it to a solid color?** I'm not sure whether specific elements on the canvas should be removed, or if re-painting it blank is all that has to be done. I'm pretty new to canvas altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flood-fill a canvas with a solid color like this:

```
context.fillStyle='skyblue';

context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

There's no need to individually "erase" previous drawings because they are just pixels on the canvas that get overwritten with the new fillRect.

If you want to clear the canvas (where all pixels are fully transparent) you can do this:

```
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Cheers!